# How to convert dd.mm.yy date format in excel 2007 date

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me to get excel(2007) date format 'DD-MM-YYYY' for the following non-standard date format.

" 01.11.65" having leading space. 
"'01.11.65" having leading single quote mark.
"15.11.50"  having shown as "3.11.50 PM" in formula bar.

Comment: Do you mean you have the data in the non-standard format already? Or you have a date and you want to display it in the non-standard format?

Comment: Yes, I have data in the non-standard date format already for around 450 records of excel 2007 sheet.

Comment: one way (if you want to stay completely within Excel) is to combine usages of the DATE function, the VALUE function and the MID function.

Comment: For example, if your A1 cell is " 01.11.65" (which represents 11/1/1965?) you could use a formula such as this: =DATE(VALUE(MID(A1,8,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,5,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,2,2)))